# Getting NullReferenceException Error While Trying To Remove Dynamical Content in C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, dynamic, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to develop a program that calculates the average grade of a semester with Windows Forms Application.
Well, first I have a combobox and a button for deciding the number of lesson I take at that semester. When I select the number of lesson and click the button, it creates the amount of textbox(es) I want. There is nothing to worry about at this part.
http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/01/26/Ads%C4%B1z.png
http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/01/26/Ads%C4%B1z1.jpg

The problem that bugs me is the deletion of the dynamical contents. I think deleting and re-creating contents dynamically is a well idea for changing the amount of lesson more than once. This is my code for my solution.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int Syc = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k <= 15; k++) {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(k);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int En = 50;
        int Item=Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        TextBox[] d1 = new TextBox[Item];
        ComboBox[,] d2 = new ComboBox[Item,2]; //Planning to use it afterwards
        if (Syc == 1) Sil(d1); // Controls if the combobox changed before
        Syc = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < Item; k++) {
            d1[k] = new TextBox();
            d1[k].Name = "textBox" + (k+1).ToString();
            d1[k].Location = new Point(10,En);
            d1[k].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 15);
            d1[k].Text = "";
            this.Controls.Add(d1[k]);
            En += 25;

        }
    }
    private void Sil(TextBox[] d1) { //This part should have deleted
                         //the dynamical content that created before
        for (int k = d1.Length-1; k >=0; k--) {
            this.Controls.Remove(d1[k]);
            d1[k].Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Well, I get a NullReferenceError at the line where d1[k].Dispose exists in Sil function. I feel really confused because there shouldn't be any reason for this kind of error. I created the instances of the textbox(es) and I even tried this again in Sil function.
What do I miss here or what kind of solution would you suggest?

Comment: I think this is a bug fix IMO :)

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error message. Also, in most cases debugging can solve such errors.

Comment: Debug the code. You are messing up with array indexing and variable handling ..

Answer (score 0):

1. Where do you reset `Syc` to 0?
2. If you select 4, resulting in 4 `TextBox`s and `Syc`=1, then select 6, how is your code *not* going to call `Dispose` on null pointers at `d1[4]` and `d1[5]`?

Set some breakpoints and see. (Hint: I'm pretty sure you want your call to `Sil` to precede your call to `d1 = new TextBox[]`, and that somewhere in there, you're going to want to set `Syc = 0`.)